# CPQ - How to create Tiered Pricing by Year for Renewals in CPQ

Tags: quote, cpq, pricing

We have some products that for specific states we are forcing them from Legacy to Premium or Plus to Premium during renewal time.

For States where we are forcing customers to go to Premium (one of the two options above), we want to offer the following automatic stair steps:

1. Legacy to Premium: Stair Step to $2.00 in year 1, $2.50 in year 2, and $2.75 in year 3 for Legacy Customers.
2. Plus to Premium: Stair Step to $2.50 in year 1, $2.75 in year 2 for Plus customers.

Is this possible? How would it be designed?

Answer (score 0):

Use MDQ: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_mdq_products.htm&type=5

And a price rule, referencing the "segment index" field. This field only populates for MDQ products, and if your segment type is annual, the number represents years. You can use an advanced formula action to conditionally apply percentages, or use lookup queries to explicitly define "product + year" pricing values.